# How do I get ffmpeg.exe to function on a cloud hosting site like Discloud?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py

So to keep my Discord bot running 24/7, I use the hosting site Discloud. I just added music playing capabilities to my bot, and they function fine when I run the bot locally, because it can access the .exe file for ffmpeg through the file path I have put in the code through the play command.

Code:

```
@bot.command(name='play', help='To play song')
async def play(ctx, url):
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel

    if voice_channel is None:
        return await ctx.send('You are not connected to a voice channel.')

    async with ctx.typing():
        filename = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=bot.loop)
        
        if ctx.voice_client is not None:
            ctx.voice_client.stop()

        source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
            executable="C:\\Users\\Scarlett Rivera\\Documents\\ffmpeg\\ffmpeg.exe",
            source=filename
        )
        
        voice_channel.play(source)

    await ctx.send('**Now playing:** {}'.format(filename))
```

However, whenever I try to use the play command while the bot is running through Discloud, it gives me this error in the logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 235, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/user_686208406444572830/Sc4rl3ttb0t.py", line 351, in play
source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 290, in __init__
super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 166, in __init__
self._process = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 183, in _spawn_process
raise ClientException(executable + ' was not found.') from None
discord.errors.ClientException: C:\Users\Scarlett Rivera\Documents\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe was not found.
  
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1029, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 244, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: C:\Users\Scarlett Rivera\Documents\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe was not found.
```

I've tried reaching out to another programmer who helped me yesterday with programming my bot to fulfill the main purpose I wanted from it, and they weren't able to come up with anything because they don't have any experience with Discloud. If anyone at all could help me, that would be extremely appreciated

Comment: There's very little hope here.  Your code assumes a Windows host, but Discloud is running Linux.  Unless they can tell you that ffmpeg is installed or have a way to ask for it, you can't do this.  Have you tried simply saying `executable="ffmpeg"`?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that yet. I'll try it and see what happens

Comment: Have tried to read the docs of discloud? On the link i provided it tells you how to to this [Link to the docs](https://docs.discloudbot.com/v/en/configuration/configuration/apt)